# What does this symbol denote in arithmetic, Z*?

Tags: arithmetic

I know Z+, means all positive integers, but what does Z* means?

Comment: What is the context? Can you give an example of how the symbol is used?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, my context is basic arithmetic and number theory, is this question very basic?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I tried to find it here, but I could not find exact question!

Comment: Can you give an example of how it is used? Where did you see it? (E.g. I have also seen it used to denote the set of *nonzero* integers.)

Comment: You should give the source so that we can be sure, but I'm fairly certain that Divyanshu's answer is **wrong** in this context: I think "$\mathbb{Z}_p$" is probably the ring of integers mod $p$ (also denoted "$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$"), and $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is then the set of *invertible elements* of this ring.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, but I asked this question as a context of basic number theory, i.e. Z*, not in the context of Zp*

Comment: Have you actually seen the notation $Z^*$ used on its own in this context? If so, how - can you give an example? Note that the accepted answer can't possibly apply to Zp*, since there's no notion of "positive element" there. And the only example of this notation you've given is in the context of Zp.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, the link sent in the accepted answer, go and first have a look!

Comment: Yes, *sometimes that symbol is used that way*. But presumably, if you're asking the question, *you've seen it somewhere already*. And symbols in math can be used for different things at different times. Based on the context you've given, I am fairly certain the accepted answer is incorrect *for your context*. If you want to clarify this, you should give more examples of how **you** have seen this used. So far the only example you have given is Zp*, which is **definitely not** used the way the accepted answer describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this,

- Integers are denoted by Z, i.e. `{. . ., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, . . .}`
- Z^+ denotes all positive integer sets i.e. `{1, 2, 3,  . . .}` equivalent to N, Natural numbers.
- Z^- denotes all negative integer sets i.e. `{-1, -2, -3, . . .}` and
- Z^* denotes all non-negative integers, i.e. `{0, 1, 2, 3,  . . .}`

For more information about arithmetic, go to [Signed Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Z-Star.html)

Hope this clarifies!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's comment, I think the accepted answer is incorrect in this context. I think "$\mathbb{Z}_p$" is probably the ring of integers mod $p$ (also denoted "$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$"), and $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is then the set of *invertible elements* of this ring. E.g. if $p=6$ then $\mathbb{Z}_p^*=\{[1], [5]\}$.

*Note that really "$\mathbb{Z}_p$" shouldn't be used in this way - it conflates with the notation for the [$p$-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number). But this is a common, if unfortunate, bit of notation.*

Comment: -1: Out of context, based on OP's comment, `@NoahSchweber, but I asked this question as a context of basic number theory, i.e. Z*, not in the context of Zp* `

Comment: @StellaBiderman, Out of context, based on OP's comment, `but I asked this question as a context of basic number theory, i.e. Z*, not in the context of Zp*`

Comment: @DivyanshuKushwaha The OP deleted an important comment of theirs: when asked to give an example of this notation, they gave (quoting from memory) "let $\alpha$ be an element of order $q$ in $Z_p^*$". So the only example they gave *did* use $Z_p^*$, not $Z^*$. I asked them for another example, to clarify, and this is where they started insulting me. But at present, except for the OP's odd protestations, all the evidence they've given does suggest this interpretation.

Comment: @DivyanshuKushwaha You can see evidence of the deleted comment: note that as it stands, I seem to bring $Z_p^*$ into the comment thread for no reason. Immediately before my comment first mentioning $Z_p^*$, was the now-deleted comment by the OP.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It's probably worth amending this answer to note that the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\{-1,1\}$. Technically you haven't answered the question, just explained the context.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, All this made me so curious, so what exactly Zp* is? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180657/what-is-zp-in-this-scenario