# What is $\Bbb Z_p^*$ in this scenario?

Tags: group-theory, arithmetic, cryptography

Let $\alpha$ be an element of order $q$ in $\Bbb Z_p^*$, where $p$ is a large prime number such that $p-1$ has large prime factor $q$. Also, what it means by order?

Comment: In Group theory, if G be a group then every $a\in G$ has a order i. e smallest positive integer $k$ such that $a^k=e$. I think $Z_p*$ is  multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$.

Comment: @C.F.G, So what will be the answer if p =7?

Comment: If $p=7$, what is the question? You want to know the order of the group?

Comment: @mikeazo, yes just explain!

Comment: You cannot  @-ping users who have not participated in this thread. A) the pings don't work at all, B) many think they are rude. So I just removed those comments.

Comment: I am sure your textbook defines what the order of an element in a group means. Do look it up!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, okay thanks!

Comment: As an example (see my answer) :for $p=7$, the order of $2$ : $2, 2^2= 4, 2^3 = 8 =1$ so $o(2) = 3$. $3^1 = 3, 3^2= 9= 2, 3^3 = 6, 3^4 = 18= 4, 3^5 = 12= 5, 3^6 = 15= 1$, so $o(3) = 6$ ;it generates the whole group.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, How to find the number of generators in the group?

Comment: There is at least one, the number is about the order of $\log(|G|)$ IIRC. Why ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I was reading a discussion and I found this, "Finding generators of a cyclic group depends upon the order of the group. If the order of a group is n then the total number of generators of group G are equal to positive integers less than n and coprime to n" Also, how to find all other generators if one generator is known?

Comment: If $g$ is a generator and the group of order $n$ then $g^k$ is another generator if $(k,n) = 1$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, So can we say that the total number of generators in a group is equal to the Euler's totient function for the order of that group i.e. If the order of a group is n then total number generators will be ϕ(n)?

Comment: In a cyclic group yes.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Thanks! I got negative reviews for this question, can you suggest me a way on how to improve or fix the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_p^{\ast} = \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \{0\}$, which is a group under muliplication (modulo $p$). The order $o(g)$ of some $g \in G$ where $(G, \cdot, 1)$ is any finite group, is just $o(g) = \min \{n \in \mathbb{N}^+: g^n = 1\}$

(which exists by well-orderedness of the naturals and finiteness of $G$: we just keep taking powers of $g$ until we reach a repeated element $g^k = g^l$ for some $k < l$ and then $g^{l-k} = 1$. So the set we take a minimum of is non-empty.) (nice fact: $o(g)$ is always a divisor of the group size $|G|$)

We then have that $\{g, g^2, g^3, \ldots ,g^{o(g)}=1\}$ is the subgroup generated by $g$. In this subgroup every element has a logarithm over $g$, by definition $\log_g(g^k) = k$, and in a large group finding the logarithm of some arbitary element in it (bu not given as $g^k$ of course)  is a supposedly hard problem. So you need elements of large order. In fact in $\mathbb{Z}_p^\ast$ which has size $p-1$, there are even elements of order $p-1$ and also of every divisor of $p-1$, so e.g. of order $q$. These groups generated by such elements are then used in Diffie-Helman protocols, etc. to link it back to cryptography.

Comment: Zp∖{0} , does this means all elements except zero?

Comment: @DivyanshuKushwaha Yes. All non-zero elements have an inverse for multiplication modulo $p$